# Access control and XHR requests

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, authorization, acl

I'm struggling with access control implementation for custom framework.

RBAC granularity is not needed so I decided to go with some kind of ACL where resources will be
controller actions.

Here is the database structure:

users:

- John
- Mary
- Greg

user_groups:

- Administrators
- Accountants
- Managers

users_to_user_groups:

- John => Administrators
- Mary => Accountants
- Greg => Managers

resources (controller actions):

- users/edit
- invoices/add
- customers/delete

resources_to_user_groups:

- users/edit => Administrators
- invoices/add => Accountants
- customers/delete => Managers

And here is the [pseudo]code.

```
$user = new User; // This will be currently logged in user ...

$acl = new Acl($user);

$dispatcher = new Dispatcher($acl);

$dispatcher->dispatch('users', 'new');

class Dispatcher
{
    public function dispatch($controller, $action)
    {
        $permission = $controller . '/' . $action;

        if(!$this->acl->isAllowed($permission))
        {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access denied");
        }

        // User is authorized to execute this action, dispatch ...
    }
}
```

I liked this approach... until I realized that there is also many XHR requests.

For example, invoice list uses XHR request to get total amount, order list uses XHR requests
to load order positions and other data etc.

So, there must be some resource grouping, for example, new table resource_groups:

- Invoice list (invoices/list, invoices/xhr_get_total_amount)
- Order list (orders/list, orders/xhr_get_positons_for_order, orders/xhr_get_some_other_data)
- Add new user (users/new) # Single action, new user entry form does not use XHR requests

... and instead of assigning resources to user groups, assign resource groups to user groups.

Feels so complicated. Is this the correct way to do it? What can be improved? Does any framework address this problem?

Comment: Why should XHR matter?  The same user with the same permissions is accessing the same resource in the same way, it's just packaged up and delivered to the client in a different way.  If there's more to it than that, then there's not nearly enough information here to be able to provide any meaningful help to you.

Comment: Jason - because single 'resource' (better wording is 'activity' as DudeOnRock mentioned) can consist of single static HTTP request or in addition call one or more XHR requests. So, we can't assume, that each controller::action pair is 'permission', we need to somehow group them.

Comment: I feel as though you've made a wrong turn somewhere. If you're creating permissions based on "requests" (or, to be as literal as possible, each URL has its own specific permission) then you're headed down a path that's impossible to maintain. Creating groups to add those requests to merely abstracts the maintenance issue slightly. Now, you won't be the first person to have taken this approach (the legacy system in use at my work, originally based on osCommerce, controls access per filename), but if your application is now or has aspirations to be any even modest size, you're in for headaches.

Comment: Yes, you are right about my initial plan whan each controller::action pair (or URL) needs separate permission. But as I mentioned at the end of post, I see need for grouping some actions together to form a single permission / activity.
What is your suggested approach? I give you an example - activity "View logs" which consists of 2 controller actions - one static HTTP request which draws some table HTML markup and in this page is also one XHR request which gets latest log records, let's say, every 30 seconds. How do you merge those under single permission?

Comment: @LaurisB: you XHR request can call several different functions that represent an activity in the receiving script. If some of those functions don't need permissions, that is fine, if all of them do, authenticate each activity individually.

Comment: @DudeOnRock: Can you elaborate on that with simple example? Do I need to authenticate against anything else than controller actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been dealing with the same problem in the past year and here's how I tackled it.

First of all I used [Zend Framework's ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.html) library as the base engine to tell me if some user has access to some resource. As ZF already supports user grouping and roles (including role hierarchy) you don't need to worry about that anymore.

Putting user grouping and roles aside, next would be resource grouping which ZF does not support internally (sadly). And I believe this is the part your question concerns. Yet you can use ZF and extend it to fit your needs. All you need to do is to come up with a grouping mechanism for resources (flat or hierarchical). Then you can make use of ZF as it is instructed in their manual.

Here's an example on how to do it:

1. Construct the ACL engine and other basic objects:

   ```
   $acl = new Zend_Acl();

   $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'))
       ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('member'))
       ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));

   $parents = array('guest', 'member', 'admin');
   $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('someUser'), $parents);
   ```
2. Define your resource grouping:

   ```
   $resources = array(
       'group 1' => array(
           'resource 1'
           , 'resource 2'
           , 'resource 3'
       )
       , 'group 2' => array(
           'resource 1'
           , 'resource 4'
           , 'resource 5'
       )
   );
   ```
3. Introduce your resources to the ACL's engine:

   ```
   function addResource(Zend_Acl $acl, $resources, $groupName)
   {
       foreach ($resources[$groupName] as $resource) {
           $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource($resource));
       }
   }

   addResource($acl, $resources, 'group 2');
   ```
4. Use the ACL's engine to query permissions:

   ```
   echo $acl->isAllowed('someUser', 'resource 1') ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
   ```

As you can see I didn't do anything special here. The only new concept introduced here was that the resources added to the ACL engine was different from the ones used to query it. But it was done a layer before we actually call ZF's library so calls to query ZF's ACL still works.

I hope I could write down my point of view clearly. And don't forget I'm just trying to give you a concept, you need to come up with the actual implementation yourself.

Comment: Yes, this is similar what I thought about resoruce grouping. I'll go with custom implementation though where resource groups will be 'permissions'.

Comment: Personally I believe a hierarchy of resources are more useful. In that case all you need to keep in mind is to use paths instead of group names. Like `/branch 1/branch 1.1` which means you have an array in PHP like `$resources['tree']['branch 1']['tree']['branch 1.1']`. And you need to combine the arrays `$resources['resources']` and `$resources['tree']['branch 1']['resources']` and `$resources['tree']['branch 1']['tree']['branch 1.1']['resources']` to make the list of resources they come with. I'm sure you can figure out the necessity of using `tree` and `resources` entries yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add new column to `resources` table, called `descendants`, which will store an array of depending xhr resources? So it could look like:

```
resource: "invoices/list"
descendants: ["invoices/xhr_get_total_amount"]

resource: "orders/list"
descendants: ["orders/xhr_get_positons_for_order","orders/xhr_get_some_other_data"]

resource: "users/new"
descendants: []
```

Also, if not implemented yet: you can get and process the whole list of allowed resources and their descendants to a single array at the beginning of request and store them until response. So you will not ask database every time you need to check something an access.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am not directly answering your question, but maybe I can send you on a slightly different path that is going to be a lot more flexible once your web site grows in size and complexity. After I read [this](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/) post I have switched my authentication system to activity based (allow activity "doSomething"), away from role based ("administrator" can do the following....).

Just a thought.

Comment: How do you deal with permission management when some 'activity' uses XHR?
For example, activity "Add new user" which in addition to HTML form rendering (users/new) uses XHR to get some data (for example, changing HTML form's country combo, gets cities for this country like users/xhr_get_cities_by_country_id).

Comment: the activity "addNewUser" should not be responsible for any output itself. It should just add a new user to the database.

Comment: My bad, with "Add new user" I thought of new user form. Like in REST naming: users/new (form) => users/create (add to DB) and users/edit/5 (form) => users/update/5 (update to DB).

Answer (score 1):

It is preferred to not use * but the domain that is requesting the file.
The * will fail in some version of IE (do not remember wich).

```
if ($ref_url)
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"+$ref_url);
else
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```